# How to display only one region on jvector map

Tags: jvectormap

Is there anyway to show only one region on  jvector map . After this i have to highlighted particular city on that region onclick event below is the code that i have tried.

```
    <li><a href="#" rel="gb">United Kingdom</a>


<div id="map"></div>

var wrld2 = {
    map: 'world_mill',
    normalizeFunction: 'polynomial',
    regionStyle: regionStyling,
    backgroundColor: 'none',
    regionsSelectableOne: true,
    regionsSelectable: true,
    series: {
        regions: [{
            values: {},
            attribute: 'fill'
        }]
    }
};

$('#map').vectorMap(wrld2);


var mapObj2 = $('#map').vectorMap('get', 'mapObject');

function findRegion(robj, rname) {
    var code = '';
    $.each(robj, function (key) {
        if (unescape(encodeURIComponent(robj[key].config.name)) === unescape(encodeURIComponent(rname))) {
            code = key;
        }
    });
    return code;
}


$('ul').on('click', 'a:first-child', function (event) {
    var elem = event.target,
        evtype = event.type,
        cntrycode = findRegion(mapObj2.regions, $(elem).text());

    if (evtype === 'click') {
        mapObj2.clearSelectedRegions();
        mapObj2.setSelectedRegions([cntrycode]);
    }
});
```

Is there any method? http://jsfiddle.net/gwdhzaLb/2/